# EC2 and Route53 are not direct to correct folder

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

Forgive me if I am doing wrong, I have built a Wordpress through Ubuntu tier on e2, and it's fine and went well and it shows
http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/yunshantea/

then I use Route53 for hosting zone direct to domain http://www.yunshan-tea.com/ it works fine and it right direct to IP address for "http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/"  and it works fine but it shows apache dashboards, but I have tried to put /yunshantea on route53 but they said they won't accept /yunshantea location folder where the wordpress site at.

Can anyone advice me, as i am not familiar with AWS ec2 and Route53 as all new to me.

Do I need Redirect at Apache HTTPS.conf or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using AWS ALB

1. Host your wordpress installation directly on `http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`
2. Create an ALB and register the EC2 server under that ALB
3. Now using AWS ALB point your `/yunshantea` to the wordpress installation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html
4. Now point the CNAME to the ALB and you are done

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try it, Sorry for the delay, Was out of the desk and unable to reach the technology world for the weekend, I already install the WordPress. so I cannot install again to start all over again.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this by Route53 alone. You can point a domain to specific server using A record or CNAME record but you cannot point it to a local directory using Route53.
You will have to create virtual hosts in apache to point specific domain to a content from specific local directory.

[Apache Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)